# Assigning object instance to integer var in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Within the main method create an Object instance and assign it to an integer variable.
When an exception is thrown handle it using try catch and print a message in catch clause.
I have no idea what to do.I did this:

```
public class Ch7LU1Ex4{

   public static void main(String argv[]) {   

     try{

       Object o = new Integer(10);
       int b = (Integer) o;

     }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.print("Exception caught");
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? How to format/indent code?

Comment: The first 2 lines is the question.Making such an assignment and then catch the exception.I don't understand how to assign an object to an integer variable. What I did there I think is converting an object to integer.Not what they wanted.

Comment: @Robin check the answers, probably thats what the assignment means.

Comment: well it was a part of a JAVA studying course.why?

Answer (score 2):

You have done what the assignment asked (although I would code it without the auto-unbox as `Integer i = (Intsger)o;`), but you won't get an exception because the cast will work - casting an Integer to an Integer won't cause an Exception.

Try this:

```
Object o = new Object(),
```

You will then exercise your catch code

Comment: Thank you so muchhh :) Its done.I was just not being able to figure out how to make an exception.It was working properly all the time xD Thanksss ><

Answer (score 2):

The assignment is quite strange (it tells you to implement a bug, basically), but I think what the teacher wants is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {   
    try {
        Object o = new Object();
        Integer b = (Integer) o;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        System.out.print("An Object is not an Integer. The above makes no sense");
    }
}
```

Maybe to make you realize that only Integer instances can be cast to an Integer.